# Is it possible to kill an app (iOS Simulator) when I switch user accounts on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, mac

In Mac OSX Lion, if you open multiple copies of the iOS simulator on multiple user accounts, the simulator won't work. There is a bug with shared use of the simulator and OSX fast user switching.

Is it possible to automatically close the simulator, whenever I switch user accounts? I end up having to switch back and kill the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to switch accounts. You should be able do so something like

```
sudo killall "iOS Simulator"
```

Or you can put that in a script and add it to your startup items, or add it as a per-user `launchd` job under `/Library/LaunchAgents`.  You might have to edit `/etc/sudoers` to allow any account to run that command/script.